# How to make a box transition smoother in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to find some information  about this, but I cant find some good information.
I want to make a div, that says "Contact Us" and when you click on the div, a layer shows up smoothy with input types.

I know that I can make some quick javascript to change from display:none to display:block, but how can I do it smooth?

for an example (just a quick example, the actual one will be better)

```
<div id="contact-us" onClick="showContactUs()">
<div id="contact-us-content" style="display: block;">
  Name - <input type="text" name="name">
  Email- <input type="text" name="email">
</div>
</div>
```

And then javascript is

```
function showContactUs(){
   var r = document.getElementById("contact-us-content");
   r.style.display = "block";
}
```

If any of you have any tips, or a link I can check I would appreciate it.
I am not that good with jquery, but can absolutely try some if you think its better.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://api.jquery.com/show/ ? It has some animation options

Comment: `$(function() { $("#contact-us").on("click",function() {$("#contact-us-content").show("easing");});`

Comment: You want this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make the appearing smooth by setting `display: block`. You can, however, transition **opacity**. I suggest adding a class by javascript and solving the rest by css.

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/3wLrfk3d/

```
$(document).on('click', '#contact-us', show_contact_form)

function show_contact_form () {
    $('#contact-us-content').addClass('shown')
}
```

css:

```
#contact-us-content {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;

    &.shown {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

My example uses jquery and sass, I am sure you will be able to rewrite it to vanilla and css.

Answer (score 2):

I usually transition the opacity, but that will mean the element will be there even if it's invisible, taking up space and blocking mouse events. I solve this by having two classes, one to fade the element and one to hide it completely when it's done fading out:

```js
$(function() {
 var $box = $('.box');
 $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  if (!($box).hasClass('visible')) {
     $box.addClass('transitioning');
   setTimeout(function() {
       $box.addClass('visible');
      }, 1)
    } else {
     $box.removeClass('visible');
      setTimeout(function() {
      $box.removeClass('transitioning');
      }, 400)
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.box {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  border: 5px solid white;
  padding: 50px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.transitioning {
  display: block;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}

.toggle {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">Toggle Box</button>
<div class="box">
  <h1>Hi there</h1>
</div>
```

Note: this is a quick and dirty example, it kinda freaks out if you spam clicks on the toggle button, I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: I will absolutely check this up, it was something similar to this I was searching for.  However, if I dont want a button, lets say I want a span element that I can click on, it doesnt matter as long as the class is still ="toggle" and "box" ?

Comment: Exactly, you can make anything clickable